# making .ajax request to mvc controller - but .done function never executes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

So basically Here is what I do:

in body - onload method I call this javascript function

```
        function TestN() {
            var list = new Array();
            var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

            $("*[wordNum]").each(function ()
            {
                var endRes = {
                    ControllerName: this.id,
                    WordNumber: this.getAttribute("wordNum")
                };

                list.push(endRes);


            });


            jQuery.ajax({
                url:' @Url.Action("Translate")' ,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { List : JSON.stringify(list) }
,
                traditional: true

            })
        }
```

what it does - it searches all the controlls with attribute "WrdNum" and then I make an ajax request to the MVC Translate action!

In the Translate Action I make  a request to a web service which populates a list of type - `TranslateModel`

```
public ActionResult Translate(string List)
        {

       List<TranslateModel>listto = WebServiceBea.TranslateList(1, List);

        return View(listto); 

    }
```

Also Here is my TranslateModel

```
 public class TranslateModel
    {
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public string WordNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

So basically my question is -> what type should I return to a view - > and how to return this list to a javascript or jquery function which has to set the innerHtml property of some html controls with the record from this list.**

I now that it's strange but that's my task

---

**EDIT**

Thanks so much for the help. But now I've got another problem:

After I changed my javascript and put. Done method so I could get the data from the server it looks something like this :

$(document).ready(function () {
            var list = new Array();

```
        $("*[wordNum]").each(function () {
            var endRes = {
                ControllerName: this.id,
                WordNumber: this.getAttribute("wordNum")
            };

            list.push(endRes);


        });


        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ' @Url.Action("Translate")',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { List: JSON.stringify(list) }
```

,
                traditional: true,

```
        }).done(function (result)
        {


           alert ("HII") ;


        });
    });
```

no matter what I put in the .done function it never executes. It seems like the controller doesn't know where to return the result. |I| don't now. Can something happen from the fact that I'm making this request from the .layout page - on document ready.  s

Comment: Is this going to *only* be called from javascript? If so, easiest thing to do would be to return the list as json and parse it with javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this looks like a greet place to use [knockout js](http://knockoutjs.com/).
here is a great [step by step](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/knockout-js-and-bootstrap-with-asp-net-mvc-part-2) for using knockout with the mvc view

so the method will only return json, the view will not have a model just a call to get the json

if you are going to use $.post to pull your data you could return your list as json

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get|HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Translate(string List)
{

   List<TranslateModel>listto = WebServiceBea.TranslateList(1, modelObj);

    return Json(listto); 
}
```

Looking at what you are posting to the action method, it should already be a list of that type. MVC should do the heavy lifting and transform it to the objects you have.

if however you would like to handle the return yourself you can do something like

```
           jQuery.ajax({
            url:' @Url.Action("Translate")' ,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { List : JSON.stringify(list) },
            traditional: true

        }).success(function( returnData, returnStatus)
        {
            //some code to handle the list of objects reutrned
        });
```

Comment: Hello - thank you very much! I added some code which I suppose would clarify the situation. and I would be really thankful for some more help

Comment: what is the purpose of sending the list to the action? dont you want to get the list from the action based on some var? just need some clarification.

Comment: So as I saID WHEN MVC has stopped rendering view and html is ready I've got some special controlls whith attribute "wrdNum". I colect their values and send them to Action Translate. Than based on that argument Translate action populates a list; and somehow this list has to be received by the javascript function so I can set some attributes of these special controls

Comment: sorry missed that part {blush} lol. i just changed my answer a little. hope it helps

Comment: Is there another way : for examole when I make an ajax request I think there was a property:Success: SomeFunction(with parameter that list); or   .done:DOSomething()

Comment: Hello Thank you very much -> but the strangest thing is that nothing happens; even if I put in the onsuccess function only alert("Hi") it doesn't execute at all

Comment: @MilkaSalkova you should add handlers for error then, odds are there something is causing an error. the .done will get called every time success or fail. you can use the debug tool in chrome, there is a section for reviewing requests and you can inspect the error there to try and figure out your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got an answer, but consider the following for cases where you may have controller actions called by javascript:

```
public ActionResult GetItems(string id)
{
    var MyList = db.GetItems(id);//returns a list of items
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())//called from javascript via AJAX
        {
            return Json(MyList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else //regular hyperlink click
        {
            return View(MyList);
        }
}
```

To use the list, do the following

```
$.ajax({url: "'@Url.Content("~/controllername/GetItems")?id=' + id"})
 .done(function(result){
        var mylist = result.responseText.evalJSON();//this is your list of items
        for(i=0;i<mylist .length;i++)
        {
            var myitem = mylist[i];
        }

    });
```

Comment: can you help me - how to get this list in the javascript: maybe in the ajax request I should put success:SOmeFunction()

Answer (score 0):

NEVERRRR NEVERRR Forge to put  `jsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

Thanks alot for everyone for the help